# LPTHW exercise 39 tuple unpacking

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out why this code:

```
states = {
    'Oregon': 'OR',
    'Florida': 'FL',
    'California': 'CA',
    'New York': 'NY',
    'Michigan': 'MI'
}

print '-' * 10
for state, abbrev in states.items():
    print "%s is abbreviated %s" % (state, abbrev)
```

which gives this output:

```
----------
California is abbreviated CA
Michigan is abbreviated MI
New York is abbreviated NY
Florida is abbreviated FL
Oregon is abbreviated OR
```

is coming out in this particular order? Shouldn't the output be in the order that's in the dictionary?

ie. I would think that it'd come out like:

---

```
Oregon is abbreviated OR
Florida is abbreviated FL
California is abbreviated CA
New York is abbreviated NY
Michigan is abbreviated MI
```

Comment: Dictionaries do not maintain order

Comment: BTW, This is very bad title for your question. It says nothing about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries do not have inherent order. Use collections.OrderedDict if you care about the ordering of items in a dict.